Ссылка в боте. Telebot
Коллеги, спасайте. Кусок кода:
        telegram_username = 'AnnaBrich'
        telegram_link = f'https://t.me/{telegram_username}'
        bot.send_message(
            call.from_user.id,
            f"Ты зарегистрировалась на <b><i>Душевную встречу о том, "
            f"как всё успеть</i></b> с {telegram_link}, которая пройдёт ...")

В сообщении от бота ссылка выглядит так:  https://t.me/AnnaBrich.
Как настроить, чтобы отображалось так: Анна Бричка?

Забыл сказать, использую parse_mode="HTML"

Ну воспользуйтесь HTML: <a href="https://example.com">Example</a>

Сделал так ещё вчера, но помимо нужной мне ссылки, внизу сообщения отображается предпросмотр этой ссылки, что не нужно. Нашёл, что в iogram есть disable_web_page_preview=True. Попробую так же сделать и у себя, в telebot. Или, может быть, вы знаете решение?

В telebot по идее должно быть то же самое, так что при использовании метода send_message попробуйте его применить.

Если не заработало попробуйте link_preview=False
